# Okta OWIN provider to work with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, okta

Is there a sample that shows how to use Okta as a identity and membership provider with the OWIN based Identity system in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not yet. All that we have at the moment are the the [Membership and Role providers based on SimpleMembershipProvider](https://github.com/okta/okta-music-store/tree/master/OktaProviders), used by MVC 4 and below.

Comment: Can we get an updated sample please?  I'm evaluating Okta as a potential membership provider for a new portal we're developing, but I want to use MVC 5+ for our applications.